# How to use API in Android?

Tags: android, api, httpresponse, http-get

I'm trying to use [this API](http://untiny.com/api/#service=1) in my Android app. It is very simple, you give it a [tiny URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) and it returns the original one.

This is my first time using API. So, This is how I did it:

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    String url = "http://tiny.pl/htk" //The tiny URL 
    String getURL = "http://untiny.me/api/1.0/extract?url="+url+"&format=text"; //The API service URL
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        //do something with the response
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
        output.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet)); //This is a TextView        
    }
    else {
        output.setText("null reponse");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    output.setText("exception");
}
```

My questions are:

- Is using `HttpGet` the correct way in dealing with APIs?
- **If yes,** then What mistakes I made up there? I always get "exception" in my TextView.

Comment: add e.printStackTrace(); to your catch block. Then look in your log output to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: Nothing appears. My LogCat doesn't show anything!! Are you saying that my way of dealing with APIs is correct?

Comment: No, if your TextView shows "exception" then something is going wrong. You need to add the e.printStackTrace(); call to your catch block so that you can see what exception is actually being thrown. Nothing is going to appear in your log cat until you do that.

Comment: We don't have any context for your code you are showing. Is this on a separate thread? If so you cannot touch UI elements (your textview) from a non-UI thread. If you are getting errors you should post the error you get so we can help track down the problem

Comment: @Tim: I added it already. Nothing appears.

Comment: @dymmeh: this is inside `onClick()` method.No separate threads involved here. And regarding the errors, I am getting none!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you assign "resEntityget" to a string when you convert it and reuse the string rather than trying to convert it again. Doing so will cause errors.

Try this:

```
if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE",response);
        output.setText(response); //This is a TextView        
    }
```

Comment: Then I'm not sure. I have your code working just fine with no modifications.

Comment: What is your target API when you tested it?

Comment: Targetted 2.2 (API 8). tested on a phone running 2.3.7

Comment: Then why I'm not getting it? I changed my target to API 8 and I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Are you using an emulator or an actual phone? have you tried debugging and stepping through your code to see where it fails?

Comment: I tried it in `Galaxy Nexus running 4.02` and `Galaxy Tab10.1 running 3.1`. I failed in both.

Comment: I have a Galaxy Nexus that I just tested on. I still get /GET RESPONSE(1042): http://www.google.com . Please debug your application and see which line is failing.

Comment: Also, make sure you assign resEntityget to a string when you convert it and reuse the string rather than trying to convert it again. doing so will cause errors. Do this: String response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet); and then use the variable response in your log / setting your text view

Comment: OMG, this is the damn error!! There is nothing wrong with the code `except that I didn't assign a string to resEntityget`. Thanks @dymmeh. Edit yur answer please so I can accept it. Thanks a lot mate :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I've checked there's an UnknownHostException thrown during execution.

Comment: The actual URL does work if you put it in a browser. I'm thinking if @iturki uses URL encoding the problem will resolve itself

Comment: @Olek: Weird. This is not appearing to me. Can you suggest how I solve this?

Comment: @dymmeh what do you mean by `URL encoding`? replacing the string in HttpGet with URI?

Answer (score 0):

**Is using HttpGet the correct way in dealing with APIs?**

YES

**If yes, then What mistakes I made up there? I always get "exception" in my TextView.**:

because you are passing wrong url in `HttpGet`

**Right Way:**

Fist Add url params in url:

*YOUR LOOK LIKE  :*

```
String strurl="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?page=5&sort=newest&pagesize=15";
```

*USE TinyURL “API”:*

```
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php");
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url",strurl));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = response.getEntity(); 
    tinyUrl=EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
```

Now use this url means tinyUrl as:

```
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(tinyUrl);
    HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
    HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
    if (resEntityGet != null) {  
        //do something with the response
        Log.i("GET RESPONSE",EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet));
        output.setText(EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet)); //This is a TextView        
    }
    else {
        output.setText("null reponse");
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    output.setText("exception");
}
```

OR IF YOU WANT TO USE STATIC URL THEN ENCODE URL USING  [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/) with params then pass  in `HttpGet()`
DONE!

Comment: Why are you using TinyURL API? My input URL is already a tiny one?

Comment: Yes iturki, because your full url is not encoded with parameters. if you want use static url then encode url with parameters using TinyURL API.

Comment: Your tinyURL code doesn't compile. it have some errors. for instance, `HttpMethod` cannt be resolved to a type.